# jQuery Drag & Drop data from <div> tag to <textarea> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was researching but I don't have a way to solve this problem:

I would like to drag & drop the data from `<div>` tag to `<textarea>` tag with value in `<textarea>` will be change follow to position, where I drop the `<div>` tag.

Example: value1 -> I drag `<div class="btn btn-info draggable">value1</div>` to `<textarea>Type something</textarea>` -> change to `<textarea> Type value1 something</textarea>`

This is my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: true,
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    });

    $("#MessageArea").droppable({
        hoverClass: 'active',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            this.value += " *" + $(ui.draggable).text() + "* ";
        },
    });
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Data Area</legend>
    <div class="btn btn-info draggable">value1</div>
    <div class="btn btn-info draggable">value2</div>
</fieldset>

<br />

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="MessageArea">Type something</textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="CLEAR" onclick="$('#MessageArea').val('');" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

Your code works fine when i try. Check out this pen: https://codepen.io/MortenDL/pen/yLOBZKP

However, this will not change the html values as you want. If you want the value from the textarea afterwards you can do this:

`$("#MessageArea").val()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I would like to get value from textarea after the value is changed. I would like to get value is "Type value1 something" when I drag the value1 to textarea. I think it bases on the position of the value in textarea, but I don't have many exp with jquery. If you said, we can not change the html values, have you another way to solve this case?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you're asking. Could you try to explain what you're trying to accomplish instead of what you want the html to be like? When the value of the text area is changed, you can get that value by the function written in the answer above. I've updated the pen: https://codepen.io/MortenDL/pen/yLOBZKP

Comment: Hi JohnDoe! My problem is I have textarea with value default is "Type something", I would like to drag the "Value1" (div tag) to between "Type" and "something" and drop it. The result will be changed to "Type Value1 something" and I will get this value. Apologize for my English! Thanks for your support!

Comment: I think I get want you want. I accomplished this by splitting the original sentence `type something` into an array, and then inserted the value of the draggable element in the middle, and then joining these elements into a single string. I've updated the codepen. Note that you won't be able to do this multiple times. If that is needed, you could hardcode the arr containing `["Type","something"]` into the function.

Comment: Hi JohnDoe! Your solution is so amazing! I think it worked. Thank you very much! But in the future, I have the value in textarea more length than. Ex: "This is a pen". I would like to drag the value is "special" (<div> tag) to get result is  "This is a special pen". My question is I need to check the position for value textarea in draggable, right?

Comment: Updated pen once more. This is a solution, where you can insert the value after a certain word. For instance in your above example, the word could be "a". You could change the helper function to be more advanced, or insert before a certain word or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I will try it.

Comment: Hi JohnDoe! Your solution is perfect with me and many thanks to you. Because I am a newbie only in the front-end field. I can understand your code, but how to we can know exactly the position of "Type" word when we drag <div> tag to value of textarea? As the example above, we have data in textarea is "I have a pen", I drag value is "special" to textare to get result "I have a special pen" or drag value to another position to get result is "I special have a pen" or "special I have a pen".

Comment: Ahh, i get what you want now. You want to be able do drag a word to a certain position in the text right? If yes, that's a bit more tricky. I'll see if I have time to look into it tomorrow

Comment: Thanks, JohnDoe! I have just posted a new answer below about what I want. You can review them and understand what I want. Again, I would like to say many thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post my research here because I don't know how to use codepen at the library.

It will be like this. But the data, that after I drag & drop is get url not get text of  tag.

Could you please review it and give me your comment?

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Data Area</legend>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" draggable="true">Text 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" draggable="true">Text 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" draggable="true">Text 3</a>
</fieldset>

<br />
<br />

<textarea id="MessageArea" class="form-control" rows="15" style="min-width: 100%">I have a pen</textarea>
```